# What do you call this part of the human foot?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology, image-identification

The blue color mentioned part, what do you call it in English?
(not the red part)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want to know what a layperson would call it, or what a foot doctor would call it?

Comment: I don't think a lay person would call it anything specific... "The place under my ankle bone" would be my guess but... As I said... There could be many options.

Comment: It's not really part of a leg, is it? More like the foot. Inner heel?

Comment: @Mari-LouA inner? Seems like the outside to me.

Comment: @Catija hence the question mark at the end. Dunno, I am not a doctor, but if I were going to visit one, I'd just point to the area which is hurting. The "space" between the ankle bone and [behind the heel](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/footandheelpain-140702092845-phpapp01/95/foot-and-heel-pain-9-638.jpg?cb=1404294019)

Comment: I guess you don't mean "the ankle"?  The part that is not the ankle, but around or under the ankle?  I don't think we have a name for that.

Comment: A possible answer occurred to me: do you mean the [Achilles' heel](https://www.google.com/search?q=achilles+heel)?  
The thing is that *Achilles' heel* is mostly a metaphor, meaning "a special vulnerability"; it is almost never used to literally mean that part of the foot, although that's where it is.

Comment: I'm surprised if there is a colloquial name for this part of the body in *any* language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English, but rather asks about specific medical terminology. A medical reference should be consulted.

Comment: If we were horses, that would be our fetlock, I suppose. But we aren't.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it the *ankle bone*, and that is how I would refer to it when consulting my doctor. It is just the end of the *fibula*. The medical term for it appears to be the *lateral malleolus*.

Since you appear to be asking for the name of the **space** underneath the ankle bone, I will have to disappoint you. There may be a medical term for it, but I'm not a doctor.

[WebMD: Picture of the Ankle](http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/picture-of-the-ankle#1)

Comment: The question seems to be about the space under the ankle bone...

Comment: I doubt if there is a name for that. The *inferior lateral malleolus external cavity*, perhaps?

Comment: That's my point... For learners, often times the answer is "there's not a word for that". Adding that to your answer would make it more complete. See my first comment on the question.

Comment: spot tissue under the ankle bone...

Comment: @Lambie Do you mean *soft* tissue?

Answer (score 0):

In clinical anatomical terms, this place that you pointed out is called **[lateral malleolus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbBuSozCwr4)**. I have attached for you illustration.

It is called lateral, as it's common in anatomy to call the outer part / direction- lateral while the inner part / direction is called medial.

Malleolus is the name for the distal part of the fibula bone. This name (malleolus) came from Latin meaning hammer, because its shape.

The term ankle is more general and it is a larger erea includes the medial malleolus in the second side, that it to say, on the opposite site that you pointed on. In the bottom line it includes much more erea than you wanted to point. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankle#Structure) for more details.

[image]

[image]